# Pycharm JavaScript heap out of memory on Unbuntu

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, pycharm, playwright

Extracting data from multiple urls using `scrapy-playwright` leads to following error after parsing about 1000 urls.

`FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I run Ubuntu from a virtual machine with 8k RAM and 4 CPUs.

Here's the script:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
    
install_reactor('twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor')


def r_split(x):
    return x.rsplit("/", maxsplit=2)[0]


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = spider
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    # Load competition urls to be crawled
    f = open("data.json")
    urls = json.load(f)
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, meta=dict(playwright=True))

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.css(".justify-center").css("::text").extract()

        with open("/Data/data.txt", "a+") as f:
            for ele in data:
                f.write(str(ele) + "\n")


configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
settings = get_project_settings()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)

d = runner.crawl(ExampleSpider)
reactor = asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

I cannot see where the memory leak occurs. If there's no memory leak, how can I increase the memory to prevent the error?

Comment: perhaps try rotating files you are writing to.  depending on the amount of data your are writing on each parse perhaps the size of the `data.txt` is becoming to full.  also try limiting the number of concurrent requests in the settings.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright/issues/19).